# Перевод string в integer

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Помогите, пожалуйста, перевести string в integer. 
`int x;

```
public:
    String ^text1;
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) 
{
    // x = atoi(text1.c_str()) // это не работает;
    textBox2->Text = text1;
    // нужно что бы 'x' принял значение из text1 - сюда предполагается вводить только целые числа.

}    `
```

Comment: @FFF Используйте форматирование кода.

Answer (score 4):

```
string value = "123";
int number = Int32::Parse(value);
```

Лучше оборачивать в try-catch если вы не уверенны в "качестве" строки, так как может вызывать исключение.

Comment: этот код отлично работает. спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ же? Значит строковые потоки стоит использовать для этой цели.

Comment: Это, по-видимому, C++/CLI.